# Как перехватить событие submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть форма с такой кнопкой:

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block enter" type="submit">
    Войти
    <img src="{{ asset('img/loading.gif') }}" class="img-loader" width="16" height="16" style="display: none;" alt="">
</button>
```

И код:

```
(function($, undefined) {
    $('.enter').on('submit', function() {
        $('.img-loader').css('display', 'inline');
        $('.enter').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    });
})(jQuery);
```

На форме всего два полям: логин и пароль (required). Нужно чтобы стили срабатывали при событии `submit`. Пробовал менять `submit` на `click` - все работает как надо. Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Событие `submit` [генерируется только](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/submit) для `<form>` элемента, а не для кнопок внутри него. Соответственно, и обработчик события нужно добавлять для самой формы:

```js
$("form").on("submit", function() {
  $(".enter").prop("disabled", true);
  return false; //для наглядности
});
```

```html
<form action="">
  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block enter" type="submit">Войти</button>
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

А ещё при использовании boolean-свойства `disabled` значение ему нужно присваивать соответствующее: `true` или `false`